How to calculate all possible paths between 2 neighbouring vertices on an n-dimensional hypercube?
So consider a 2-dimensional hypercube, or a square (I guess that's correct?). For a square
Path length in units | Number of Paths
1 - 1
3 - 1
And for a 3-dimensional cube
Path length in units | Number of Paths
1 - 1
3 - 2
5 - 8
7 - 2
How do you determine the number of paths for a given path length that joins 2 neighbouring vertices on an n-dimensional hypercube?

OEIS has $n=3$, length seven paths $12$. Did you make a typo in your table or am I misinterpreting the problem so that it doesn't correspond to hamiltonian cycles for the longest path?

@ploosu2 perhaps I've made a mistake? When I tried to do it I only got 2 paths. Perhaps I should specify that you cant repeat the edges you cross? If it's still 12 I will try checking on my own end.

Oh, I have made an error in my thinking. Each edge isn't necessarily used. So we must first fix an edge. Two is correct! I wonder if we get the number from https://oeis.org/A003042 by dividing by the number of edges and multiplying by $2$?

@ploosu2 Glad I could get that clarified! As for your second statement, could you perhaps elaborate a little bit? I'm just not clear with what you mean by that, sorry!
